# single and double quotes in php variable

Tags: php, javascript, string, quotes, string-concatenation

How can I combine this code with all single and double quotes as it should be.
I have tried several combinations and I can't make it work.
This one is my last try so please help.

What would be a good approach when working with long strings?

```
$html .='<a href="" onClick="$.ajax({type: "POST",url: "delete_pic.php",data:{id:"'.$row['id'].'",var:"V"},cache: false});" style="background:url("images/icons/delete.png" 50% -19px no-repeat;width:16px;height:16px;float:left;margin-left:10px;margin-top: 6px;"></a>';
```

Comment: I think the problem is in the `style` attribute part. The opening quotation for the url of the background closes the opening quotation of the `style` attribute. Maybe you should follow @Jeffrey's answer below, and separate your stylesheet rather than make it inline :)

Comment: 2 notes here: you are missing the closing ) on the url(, and as strange as it seems, you dont need any quotes around the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I follow the rule of: php strings are encapsulated in single quote, so attributes of html are in double quotes.
Any quote in the attribute must be an escaped single quote `\'`

so:

```
$html .='<a href="" onClick="$.ajax({type: \'POST\',url: \'delete_pic.php\',data:{id:\''.$row['id'].'\',var:\'V\'},cache: false});" style="background:url(\'images/icons/delete.png\' 50% -19px no-repeat;width:16px;height:16px;float:left;margin-left:10px;margin-top: 6px;"></a>';
```

Answer (score 3):

I would move your styles to an external stylesheet to make it shorter, and then just escape the quotes like "\"" for " in the string.

```
$html .="<a href=\"\" onClick=\"$.ajax({type: \"POST\",url: \"delete_pic.php\",data:{id:\".$row["\id\"].",var:\"V\"},cache: false});\" class=\"mystyle\"></a>";
```

This was not tested because I don't have your code :)

Comment: yes I understand but this is only one created element so I didn't put it in external stylesheet.

Comment: i've done that before too :) but it always comes back to bite you :)

Answer (score 3):

Best solution is to use [HEREDOC](http://php.net/heredoc), which completely eliminates the need for ANY quote escaping at the PHP level:

```
$html .= <<<EOL
<a href="onclick('\$.ajax({ etc.....

EOL;
```

Note that you'll still be bound by the quoting needs of whatever  language(s) you're embedding in the heredoc. But at least you won't have to worry about causing a PHP syntax error because of unbalanced/unescaped quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably just escape the double-quotes inside the other double-quotes (if that makes sense). :)

```
$html .='<a href="" onClick="$.ajax({type: \"POST\",url: \"delete_pic.php\",data:{id:\"'.$row['id'].'\",var:\"V\"},cache: false});" style="background:url(\"images/icons/delete.png\" 50% -19px no-repeat;width:16px;height:16px;float:left;margin-left:10px;margin-top: 6px;"></a>';
```

That (or something similar) should work.