# fancybox :how to write this statement

Tags: php, jquery, fancybox

How to include our path of image

```
<a href="image.jpg" data-fancybox="images" data-caption="My caption">
    <img src="thumbnail.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
```

I wrote code for image slideing while a click in iamge dynamicaly and i it giving me error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''  '' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in D:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\gallery2.php on line 68

```
echo '  <a href='/IMAGES/".$image."' </a> ';
echo "<img src='IMAGES/".$image."'>  ";
```

what change should done to have proper image slide

Comment: You have quoting issues. `echo '  <a href='/IMAGES/".$image."' </a> ';` will terminate the string before the `/IMAGES/` part because you're closing the single quote. I assume you have more jumbled lines like that one.

Comment: Might want to check out this question that concerns [using both single and double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16197550/single-and-double-quotes-in-php-variable) in one command.

Comment: If you use a single quote inside a single quoted literal it has the effect of terminating that string literal

Comment: main reason that you've make too many qoutations in your code echo '  <a href="/IMAGES/'.$image.'"> </a> '; as well as you don close starting <a> tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
echo '<a href="/IMAGES/'.$image.'" data-fancybox="images" data-caption="My caption">.
<img src="/IMAGES/'.$image.'" alt="" />
</a>'
```

I am assuming `/IMAGES/` is folder name not path